# Page is not updating after selecting option from dropdown element in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have this issue where I am trying to automate a process in Python that requires filling in a webpage and selecting values from dropdown menus. However, I am facing an issue where the page is not updating even after I have selected the dropdown value.

This is the code for selecting this specific element:

> ```
> import os
> import time
> import pandas as pd
> from selenium import webdriver
> from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
>
> options=Options()
> #options.page_load_strategy='none'
> options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
> options.add_argument('User_profile on mac')
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
>
> file=r'Example.xlsx'
> webpage=r'url'
>
> df_file=pd.read_excel(file)
>
> browser.maximize_window()
>
> for i,row in df_file.iterrows():
>     time.sleep(3)
>     browser.get(webpage)
>     time.sleep(3)
>    
>     WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/htm
> l/body/div[1]'))).click()
>     cat2=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/span[1]')
>
>     WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'s2id_autogen1'))).click() #looks for the first dropdown
>     WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select2-result-label-21"]'))).click() #finds the correct option
>
>     WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 's2id_autogen3'))).click() #finds the second dropdown
>     WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select2-results-4"]/li[11]'))).click() #clicks on load more
>     WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select2-result-label-34"]'))).click() #click on correct option
>    
>     problematic_dropdown=Select(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pageAside"]/div[2]/div/dep-gud-request-ors/dep-request-ors/es-view-form/form/dep-control-request-recipients/dep-control-request-recipient/div[2]/div/fieldset/dep-control-request-recipient-household/es-view-select2[1]/div/div[1]/div/select')) 
>
>     browser.implicitly_wait(3)
>
>     problematic_dropdown.select_by_value('1') #once this value is selected, the page does not load
> ```

I have tried selecting a different value and then the desired value again; I have tried using implicit and explicit waits and putting the code to sleep for 20 seconds. Unfortunately, nothing has worked. When I log into the website manually and choose the value, the page gets updated as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using better xpath selectors if you can, but for what you what to do, just click on the `option` element directly, you do not  need to expand the select box first

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="pageAside"]/div[2]/div/dep-gud-request-ors/dep-request-ors/es-view-form/form/dep-control-request-recipients/dep-control-request-recipient/div[2]/div/fieldset/dep-control-request-recipient-household/es-view-select2[1]/div/div[1]/div/select/option[@value="1"]').click
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried this method and while it does indeed select the desired option without the need to convert it first into a select object ion Python, the page still does not update. All the elements which I would like to interact with are still hidden. woudl you have any ideas on why this might be?